# How to update HTML file using Python?

Tags: python, html, azure-devops, aws-devops

Could you please help me out in updating the title section below from **"Test App Name"** to **"Demo App"**
using **Python**?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="selector-17-1">
<head class="selector-17-2">
  <title class="selector-17-4">Test App Name</title>
</head>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need Python for this? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

first install dependencies:

```
pip install lxml
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

execute

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("yourfile.html", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup("lxml", text)
soup.title = "Demo App"

with open("mynewfile.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: Sorry. doesn't work

Comment: #This worked for me

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#update index.html file
with open("index.html", "r") as inputFile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(inputFile, 'html.parser')
soup.title.string = "Demo App"
with open("indexOut.html", "w") as outFile:
    outFile.write(str(soup))